# Android Studio Failed to process jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar

Tags: android, xml, class, jar, jaxb

I am using a method which throws a JAXBException. Initially, I wrote my code in Eclipse (where I didn't have any problem), then moved it to Android Studio. Then, JAXBException was highlighted in red (catch(JAXBException){}).

So, I downloaded the "jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar" file and imported it in Android Studio. Nothing was highlighted in red. However, when I tried building the project, I had this error:

**Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\JOHN\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidDevelopment\MyApp\app\libs\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar**

I looked for it online and all I got as solution was targetted for Eclipse, not for Android Studio. From what I've read, JAXB isn't included in Android by default.

Comment: There are plenty of XML parsers for Android. Use one of those.

Comment: The extension of the file I'm trying to parse is a PMML file.

Comment: I fail to see how a [PMML file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) prevents you from using an XML parser that works on Android.

Comment: This is the first time I'm dealing with this type of file and the rest of my code uses the returned PMML object of the unmarshal method. Can other parsers return an object of type PMML?

Comment: If you create a `PMML` class and code to convert the XML representation to instances of that `PMML` class, then yes. Otherwise, find some PMML library that is supported on Android.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I only had to download a previous version of jaxb-api (**jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar**) and it worked. Btw, I'm using Java 8.